# Angular how to post data with a button using (change) detector?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to post data to my REST server. When I use a (change) it sends the data to my rest server. When I try to activate the method on my button it doesnt even try to make a POST call. How can I solve this problem? I can't find anything about it.

HTML file:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <div class="card rounded-0">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="mb-0">Organize</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="codes" class="m-2">Choose a restaurant:</label>
              <form #f="ngForm">
                <input 
                  type="text" 
                  list="codes" 
                  class="m-2"
                  (change)="saveCode($event)">
                <datalist id="codes">
                  <option *ngFor="let c of codeList" [value]="c.name">{{c.name}}</option>
                </datalist>
              </form>
              <button 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-none m-2" 
                id="btnAanmaken"
                routerLink="/menu"
                (change)="saveCode($event)"
                >Aanmaken</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript file:

```
// Method to post data to backend
  public saveCode(e): void {
    const name = e.target.value;
    const list = this.codeList.filter(x => x.name === name)[0];


    this.restaurant.name = list.name;
    this.restaurant.address = list.address;

    console.log(list.name);
    console.log(list.address);


// Additional information to the server content type
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
// Making an array with the values of the restaurant
    const data = {
      name: list.name,
      address: list.address
    };

    console.log(data);

// POST method
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant',
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) , httpOptions)

    // wait till it gets posted to the backend
      .subscribe( // subscribe to observable http.post
        res => {
          console.log("response" + " " + res); // log results otherwise log error
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        }
      );
  }
```

I tried to call the method by:

```
<button 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-none m-2" 
                id="btnAanmaken"
                routerLink="/menu"
                (change)="saveCode($event)"
                >Aanmaken</button>
```

and:

```
<button 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-none m-2" 
                id="btnAanmaken"
                routerLink="/menu"
                (click)="saveCode($event)"
                >Aanmaken</button>
```

Comment: Why is your submit button outside form tag?

Answer (score 0):

Conflict using routerLink `routerLink="/menu"` and click event.

change routing when back response.

Inject `router: Router` class and use `this.router.navigateByUrl(url: string)`
[Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)

```
 constructor(private router: Router){
  }


  public saveCode(e): void{
    // POST method
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant',
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) , httpOptions)

    // wait till it gets posted to the backend
      .subscribe( // subscribe to observable http.post
        res => {
          console.log("response" + " " + res); // log results otherwise log error

          this.router.navigateByUrl("/menu")
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: You add the router: Router in the constructor and place the  this.router.navigateByUrl(url: string) method?

Comment: Read example of `router` usage.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @Moslem, change the button type from `submit` to `button`

```
<button type="button" .. > instead of <button type="submit" ...>
```

Comment: I still cant POST any data with the button even after I tried your code